# What does Forester's "foliage density" setting do?

Tags: mcedit

I'm using [Forester](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/202591-forester-for-beta-mcedit-adds-large-trees) in MCEdit and don't know what this setting is supposed to do.

How does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Foliage* is just a fancy word for leaves: increasing the density increases the density of tree leaves when using Forester.

Comment: I know what the word means, thank you. ;) I found the explanation myself in the meantime, but thanks for your effort.